# Working unity adv plugin on cordova

Tags: cordova-plugins, unityads, heyzap

I tried
https://github.com/cranberrygame/cordova-plugin-ad-unityads
But I have integrated rewarded videos and its working fine, but once the video ends i cannot close, the app is just frozen.
Also followed the heyzapp tutorial, sadly no luck. [heyzapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEGPY.png)
Is there any other working unity adv plug-in for Cordova?
What did I wrong in config?

Comment: I am not able to integrate this plugin using cordova, bit curious about how you've managed to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin: https://github.com/Heyzap/heyzap-cordova-extras/tree/master/heyzap-cordova-unityads

I've also pushed a new version of the main Heyzap plugin here with our newest 9.12.5 sdk: https://github.com/Heyzap/heyzap-cordova

these have been tested together personally and work properly.

Comment: Tried with this two plugin... Missing permission and Network Not Enabled are still red. Unity enabled on the dasboard and also the sign is green in the Heyzap webpage, but red in the app. I checked my heyzap ID a million times and It looks the correct one. Already tried to ask for help from the support, but they told Cordova is not supported anymore.What does 'Missing permission' exactly mean?

Comment: It means that the android permissions needed for that network have not been granted or included in the manifest.  You can refer to the android docs here: https://developers.heyzap.com/docs/android_sdk_setup_and_requirements